# Ansible: become_method and ansible_become_method

Tags: ansible, sudo

What is the difference between using become_method (or become_user) and ansible_become_method in ansible playbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html):

`become_method` is a directive. These can be set from play to task level, but are overridden by connection variables as they can be host specific.

`ansible_become_method` is a connection variable. Each allows you to set an option per group and/or host, these are normally defined in inventory but can be used as normal variables.

Answer (score 0):

become_method directive is used to overrides the default method set in ansible.cfg, set to use any of the Become Plugins.This is host specific only as well said above by Hector.

ansible_become_method is connection variable describes which privilege escalation method should be used.

for eg.--:
if you want to run all tasks as root on a server named webserver, but you can only connect as the manager user, you could use an inventory entry like this:

**webserver ansible_user=manager ansible_become=yes ansible_become_method=su**